# Computer Vision questions are on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

I know that there Computer Vision themed [site in incubator](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11036/computer-vision), but it is still far enough from beta. So, is it appropriate to ask CV related questions here (since SP and CV peoples often intersect and thematic has a lot in common)?
*In particular, I'm interested to ask "structure from motion"-like question.*

Comment: I sure hope so, because that was the reason I signed up for this site

Comment: Ok, i'll ask.  
P.S. If you interested, [that's](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/107/structure-from-set-of-images) the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd say go for it, we need more questions.  Everybody may not agree, but as long as it's about the theory/practice of transforming/analyzing analog/digital signals (of any dimensionality), I'd say it's fair game.  Even if a question *could* be asked somewhere else, the discussion from a signal processing perspective could provide insights that might not come up in other contexts.

There's even a discussion of whether to merge the CV proposal with SP on Area51:

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/shall-we-merge-computer-vision-and-signal-image-video-processing

Answer (score 6):

I think the proposal I committed to was called "signal, image and video processing", based on an announcement on the OpenCV user list.

So, yes image processing and computer vision are on-topic according to me.